# Random Quoter (Using JSON File) Not Working For Some Reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My button is meant to display a random quote on page load and when the button is clicked. Looks like 'quotes' is undefined in my JS file (line 17), but I'm not sure how to remedy this. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'd really appreciate your help.

HTML:

```
                <button id="submit" type="button">Get new quote!</button>
                <span id="quoteText"></span> 
                <span id="authorText"></span>
```

JSON:

```
{ "quotes" : [

        {
            "text": "Whatever you are, be a good one.", "author": "Abraham Lincoln", "provider": "Bennett",
            "tags":["Famous Inspirational Quotes", "BrainyQuote.com", "President Lincoln"]                  
        }, 
        {
            "text": "It has been my philosophy of life that difficulties vanish when faced boldly.", "author": "Isaac Asimov", "provider": "Bennett",
            "tags":["Famous Inspirational Quotes", "BrainyQuote.com", "Science Fiction"]
        }, 
        {
            "text": "Enjoy life. There’s plenty of time to be dead.", "author": "Anonymous", "provider": "Bennett",
            "tags":["Famous Inspirational Quotes", "BrainyQuote.com", "Anonymous Quote"]
        }, 
        {
            "text": "Every moment is a fresh beginning.", "author": "T.S. Eliot", "provider": "Bennett", 
            "tags":["Famous Inspirational Quotes", "BrainyQuote.com", "Author T.S. Eliot"]
        }, 
        {
            "text": "One day your life will flash before your eyes. Make sure it is worth watching.", "author": "Anonymous", "provider": "Bennett",  
            "tags":["Famous Inspirational Quotes", "BrainyQuote.com", "President Lincoln"]
        }

        ]}
```

JS:

```
$(function() 
{
    var quoteSpan     = $("#quoteText"); 
    var authorSpan    = $("#authorText"); 
    var submitButton  = $('#submit'); 
    var data;

    $.getJSON("quotes.json", function(data) {
        window.alert(data);
    });

    var oldQuoteIndex = -1;
    var newQuoteIndex;

    function nextQuote() {
        do {
            newQuoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.quotes.length);
        } while (newQuoteIndex == oldQuoteIndex); 

        quoteSpan.text(data.quotes[newQuoteIndex].text); 
        authorSpan.text(data.quotes[newQuoteIndex].author);

        oldQuoteIndex = newQuoteIndex; 
   }
    submitButton.click(nextQuote);
    nextQuote();
});
```

Comment: `data` (in the sense of the result of your json result) is out of scope as soon as you close off that `$.getJSON()`.  Once you solve that problem, you're going to realize that it's *still* not defined because you're getting it async and `nextQuote()` is happening before `$.getJSON` returns

Comment: Shorter version: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/c59Zf/

Answer (score 0):

Call the `nextQuote` function from inside the `getJSON` callback and also setup the event from there. Then you'll have access to the data received.

```
$(function() 
{
    var quoteSpan     = $("#quoteText"); 
    var authorSpan    = $("#authorText"); 
    var submitButton  = $('#submit'); 
    var mydata;

    var oldQuoteIndex = -1;
    var newQuoteIndex;

    $.getJSON("quotes.json", function(data) {
        mydata = data;
        nextQuote();
        submitButton.click(nextQuote);
    });

    function nextQuote() {
        do {
            newQuoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * mydata.quotes.length);
        } while (newQuoteIndex == oldQuoteIndex); 

        quoteSpan.text(mydata.quotes[newQuoteIndex].text); 
        authorSpan.text(mydata.quotes[newQuoteIndex].author);

        oldQuoteIndex = newQuoteIndex; 
    }
});
```